# drop down menu in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf

I am trying to create a drop down menu, in which if a item is selected then another drop down menu should appear. Here is the code......any suggestion will be appreciable....
thanks

```
<p:selectOneMenu style="width:120px;" id="projectType"  value="#{projectManageBean.pmaster.pType}" required="true" 
                           requiredMessage="Project Type is required." >


                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />  

                                 <f:selectItems  value="#{projectManageBean.projectList}" var="ptype" itemLabel="#{ptype}" itemValue="#{ptype}" />  
                              <p:ajax  event="change" listener="#{projectManageBean.projectTypeChanged}" update="projectTypeDetai" process="@this"></p:ajax>
                              <!--   <f:ajax  render="@"></f:ajax> -->

                         </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: update="projectTypeDetai". Where is projectTypeDetai? And shouldnt it be projectTypeDetail

Comment: thanks it works...now i am facing another problem. First time when page loads and i select a item from first drop down menu then immediately child menu doesn't appear, if i refresh the page then  child menu appears.

Comment: @sandy This question has been answered, if you are having a new problem then please post a new question.  Thank you.

Comment: post your complete page source code. because I dont knwo what elements your are updating

Comment: @maple_shift Sir could you please send me the link. I am unable to search it.

Answer (score 0):

update="projectTypeDetai". Where is projectTypeDetai? And shouldnt it be projectTypeDetail